# Parameter request not returning actual value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a table that does not live in a form, but I want the button in each row to correlate and to delete the contact from that table row when it's clicked. I could do an ajax call but I was hoping to just handle it through a spring boot controller method. This is how I set it up.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/removeContact")
public String removeContact(final CarrierAppointment carrierAppointment, final HttpServletRequest req, Model model){
    final Integer rowId = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("trashContact"));
    carrierAppointment.getContactList().remove(rowId.intValue());
    model.addAttribute("carrierAppointment", carrierAppointment);
    return  "redirect:/carrierAppointment/details/"+carrierAppointment.getId();
}
```

```html
                        <table class="table table-striped" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-show-columns="true" >
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Contact Type</th>
                                <th>Contact Name</th>
                                <th>Contact's Email</th>
                                <th>Contact's Phone</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th th:if="${role.isCarrierAdmin}" class="text-right"><a class="trigger-add-contact btn btn-default" id="addCommercialContact" name="addCommercialContact"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="contact,stat : *{carrier.contactList}" th:if="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactTable}=='Commercial Lines'">
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control" th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactType}">
                                        <option value="Account Manager">Account Manager</option>
                                        <option value="Marketing Manager">Marketing Manager</option>
                                        <option value="Underwriter">Underwriter</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactName}"/></td>
                                <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactEmail}"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactPhone}"/></td>
                                <td> <input type="hidden" value='Commercial Lines' th:field="*{carrier.contactList[__${stat.index}__].contactTable}"/></td>
                                <td class="text-right" th:if="${role.isCarrierAdmin}"> <button type="button" name="trashContact" th:value="${stat.index}" th:onclick="'window.location.href=\'/removeContact\''"  class="btn btn-danger "><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

The line of code that is requesting the parameter and getting the value is where my code is getting hung up. It is returning null instead of a value. Any idea how to adjust this line of code so it actually gets the value that exists?
Maybe the way I have the onclick set up, it's not actually sending the row value through to the controller method?

This is exactly where in the code it is getting hung up:

```html
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        this.handleQueryParameters();
        ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList)this.paramHashValues.get(name);
        if (values != null) {
            return values.size() == 0 ? "" : (String)values.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```